# Why to upload file to AWS by writing to disk first?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

This example uses a file which most likely resides not in RAM:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadObjSingleOpJava.html

but I already got a buffered file from a certain client request and in the code below, this file gets written to disk, but **why** ? it makes the whole process slow by writing to disk, **can't I avoid it**?

EDIT (Below is explanation of what I am trying to achieve):

A user's image is uploaded then scaled by the server and then saved on the server's disk and only then this scaled image is sent to AWS, afterwards the user gets an aws link where the image resides on the amazon server.

```
public void transferToS3(String region, String bucket, String entity, String resolution, String filename, BufferedImage bufferedImage) {
    if (bufferedImage != null) {
        String objectpath = "/" + "images" + "/" + entity + "/" + resolution + "/" + filename + "." + "png";

        Path tmpFile = null;
        try {
            tmpFile = Files.createTempFile(imagesPath, "tmp_", ".png");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        tmpFile.toFile().deleteOnExit();

        try {
            ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "png", tmpFile.toFile());
            S3AsyncClient client = S3AsyncClient.builder().region(Region.of(region)).build();
            CompletableFuture<PutObjectResponse> future = 
                    client.putObject(PutObjectRequest.builder()
                    .bucket(bucket)
                    .key(objectpath)
                    .contentType("image/png")
                    .build(),
                    AsyncRequestProvider.fromFile(tmpFile.toAbsolutePath()));

            Path finalTmpFile = tmpFile;
            future.whenComplete((resp, err) -> {
                try {
                    if (resp != null) {
                        logger.debug(resp.toString());
                    } else {
                        logger.error(err.toString());
                    }
                    Files.deleteIfExists(finalTmpFile.toAbsolutePath());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    FunctionalUtils.invokeSafely(client::close);
                }
            });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

`Scaling` routine returns a scaled `BufferedImage` which is then used in the `transferToS3` method.

```
public BufferedImage scale(int width, int height, BufferedImage bufferedImage) {
    BufferedImage scaledBufferedImage = null;
    if (bufferedImage != null) {
        Image image = bufferedImage.getScaledInstance(width, height, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        scaledBufferedImage = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(null), image.getHeight(null), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        scaledBufferedImage.getGraphics().drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    }
    return scaledBufferedImage;
}
```

The 2 above together:

```
BufferedImage scaledBufferedImage = imageService.scale(width, height finalBufferedImage);
imageService.transferToS3(region, bucket, name, k, file, scaledBufferedImage);
```

Comment: What happens if the file is larger than your heap?

Comment: What do you want to do with the file insetad?

Comment: And then do what with it?

Comment: Do you want to return the scaled image immediately? If you can do the scaling in memory, then no, you do not need to write the file to disk.

Comment: What line of the code given here does any scaling?

Answer (score 4):

You can do whatever you wish with the data stream from the request. Feel free to scale the image in memory and send it back in the response. The example you linked writes the file to disk because this is by far the most common scenario. It also allows the author to focus on the details of uploading a file without polluting the example with unrelated code.

Note that `bufferedImage` is **not** a file. It is a stream. I suspect the author saved the image to disk in order to avoid assuming anything about the size of the image. If the image is too large to fit in RAM, then you will have difficulties doing the scaling in memory.

Comment: I am trying to improve the speed , because sometimes I feel the slow down and assuming that the images are less than 300kb maybe it's reasonable to avoid disk operations?

Comment: @Oleg Disk access is *very rarely* going to be a bottleneck in comparison to network operations.